DockerでRailsとMySQLの環境構築したいです
Dockerの学習をしているのですが、Railsでの環境構築が出来ず、行き詰まってしまいました。
実行したコマンド
docker-compose run web rails new . --force --database=mysql

発生したエラー
ffi-1.17.0-aarch64-linux-musl requires rubygems version >= 3.3.22, which is incompatible with the current version, 3.1.6

Could not find gem 'mysql2 (~> 0.5)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.

ファイル内容
Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.0'

Dockerfile
FROM ruby:2.7
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
  && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
  && apt-get update -qq \
  && apt-get install -y nodejs yarn
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./src /app
RUN bundle config --local set path 'vendor/bundle' \
  && bundle install

docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    volumes:
      - ./src/db/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development
    depends_on:
      - db


回答していただき、ありがとうございました。
無事環境構築することが出来ました。
使用していた、rubyGemsのバージョンが古いことが原因でした。
今後の方針として
今回の質問を通して、以下の2点を改善出来ればと思います。

ruby, railsのバージョンを上げて、よりモダンな環境構築をする
より具体的な質問を出来るように心がける

